# How to use jQuery remove() without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page holding a data grid generated by jQuery lets say dataGrid.php

and 2 divs on the home page some thing like this

dataGrid.php

```
<script> 
 generate the grid
</script>
<body>
<lightbox><div> close me </div>
<div >  holding the dataGrid </div>
</lightbox>
</body>
```

NOTE: I mean a popup box when I say   this is not a real valid HTML tag I am using

and here is the home page

```
<body>
<div> click here to see the grid  </div>

<div> <?php include dataGrid.php ?></div>
</body>
```

I have a close button on dataGrid.php. I am closing the include using jQuery remove() but remove() refreshes the home page which is what I don't want. I am also not sure id remove() command is really cross browser?

My question: Is there any way or method to close dataGrid.php and the light-box without refreshing the home page?

I have checked 3 other questions posted on stack-overflow with the same question title but different in the question body.

Comment: can you please show your Jquery code.?

Comment: `remove()` doesn't refresh the page at all. I don't know what `lightbox` is here, as this isn't a valid HTML element, but my guess is that you need to call `preventDefault()` on the click event.

Comment: How is that close button implemented?

Comment: code and fiddle would be great @JamesDonnelly lightbox is something like fancybox

Comment: Perhaps it looks like it's being refreshed but what happens is that you jump to the top of your page because you might use `href='#'` in your link.

Comment: @caramba that doesn't make it a valid HTML element. The HTML5 specification explicitly advises against custom elements like this.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly lightbox is an example to show how did I wrap the div

Comment: @RoySchoep  yes I am using href='#'  is that the reason ???? thanks buddy, you can post your comment as an answer ill vote it up, appreciated

Comment: @user3150692 I've already answered with what Roy was getting at in his comment (also, see my comment above his, too).

Comment: Yes if you replace `href='#'` with `href='javascript:void(0)'` it should work for you.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly oooh gosh, I didn't even see <lightbox> tag in the source code. (there was no code here before..) as I've read lightbox  I was sure he talks about this http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/.. anyway you are right of course!

Comment: @caramba the question is modified, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your close button is interactive (i.e. a hyperlink) you'll need to call `preventDefault()` on the event to prevent the browser from treating it as interactive.

Before I begin it's worth reiterating what I said in my comment on this question: `<lightbox>` isn't a valid HTML element and will fail validation tests. For this answer, however, I'm going to use this as this is given the code you've provided.

Assuming your code is something like this:

```
<lightbox>
    <a href="#" class="close">Close Me</a>
    ...
</lightbox>
```

You'd prevent the hyperlink from functioning by passing in the event and calling `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$('lightbox').on('click', 'a.close', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('lightbox').remove();
});
```

---

Alternatively you can simply change your close button to something which *isn't* interactive, like a `span` for example:

```
<lightbox>
    <span class="close">Close Me</span>
    ...
</lightbox>
```

```js
$('lightbox').on('click', 'span.close', function() {
    $('lightbox').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have it with an *onclick*, and doesn't know if the event is reachable within the function:

```
<button class="remove-form" onclick="remove_form(this);">Remove this form</button>

function remove_form(button){
    jQuery(button).parent().remove();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```